# How do I stop the Tor daemon on Mac Sierra?

Tags: mac

I recently upgraded to Mac OS X Sierra and then upgraded Tor.  However, I can’t seem to start it because evidently it is already running on my machine.  I tried this …

```
localhost:myproject davea$ tor --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort 9050 --SocksPort 50001
Nov 12 12:04:36.320 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.9 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2j and Zlib 1.2.8.
Nov 12 12:04:36.321 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/   download#warning
Nov 12 12:04:36.321 [notice] Read configuration file "/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Nov 12 12:04:36.324 [warn] Linelist option '__HashedControlSessionPassword' has no value. Skipping.
Nov 12 12:04:36.324 [warn] Option 'CookieAuthentication' used more than once; all but the last value will be ignored.
Nov 12 12:04:36.324 [warn] Linelist option '__HashedControlSessionPassword' has no value. Skipping.
Nov 12 12:04:36.324 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on   your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:50001
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:50001
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:50001: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:50001
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Nov 12 12:04:36.325 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I tried killing the tor daemon by running the below …

```
localhost:myproject davea$ pidof tor | xargs sudo kill -9
localhost:myproject davea$ pidof tor
2117 2118 2119
```

But it seem to still be running.  Does anyone know how to stop the tor daemon on Mac Sierra?

**Edit;** Below is my configuration file.  I don’t specify the ports in anything as you can see

```
## Configuration file for a typical Tor user
## Last updated 22 September 2015 for Tor 0.2.7.3-alpha.
## (may or may not work for much older or much newer versions of Tor.)
##
## Lines that begin with "## " try to explain what's going on. Lines
## that begin with just "#" are disabled commands: you can enable them
## by removing the "#" symbol.
##
## See 'man tor', or https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html,
## for more options you can use in this file.
##
## Tor will look for this file in various places based on your platform:
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#torrc

## Tor opens a SOCKS proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't
## configure one below. Set "SOCKSPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only
## as a relay, and not make any local application connections yourself.
#SOCKSPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
#SOCKSPort 192.168.0.1:9100 # Bind to this address:port too.

## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SOCKSPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SOCKSPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SOCKSPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
#SOCKSPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
#SOCKSPolicy accept6 FC00::/7
#SOCKSPolicy reject *

## Logs go to stdout at level "notice" unless redirected by something
## else, like one of the below lines. You can have as many Log lines as
## you want.
##
## We advise using "notice" in most cases, since anything more verbose
## may provide sensitive information to an attacker who obtains the logs.
##
## Send all messages of level 'notice' or higher to /opt/local/var/log/tor/notices.log
#Log notice file /opt/local/var/log/tor/notices.log
## Send every possible message to /opt/local/var/log/tor/debug.log
#Log debug file /opt/local/var/log/tor/debug.log
## Use the system log instead of Tor's logfiles
#Log notice syslog
## To send all messages to stderr:
#Log debug stderr

## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
#RunAsDaemon 1

## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows.
#DataDirectory /opt/local/var/lib/tor

## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
#ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:47EB36FD3B2B5A1860A3FB45E94ECCFD201635452E8CEB30216AEA552F
#CookieAuthentication 1

############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###

## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.

#HiddenServiceDir /opt/local/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /opt/local/var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22

################ This section is just for relays #####################
#
## See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay for details.

## Required: what port to advertise for incoming Tor connections.
#ORPort 9001
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## ORPort (e.g. to advertise 443 but bind to 9090), you can do it as
## follows.  You'll need to do ipchains or other port forwarding
## yourself to make this work.
#ORPort 443 NoListen
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise

## The IP address or full DNS name for incoming connections to your
## relay. Leave commented out and Tor will guess.
#Address noname.example.com

## If you have multiple network interfaces, you can specify one for
## outgoing traffic to use.
# OutboundBindAddress 10.0.0.5

## A handle for your relay, so people don't have to refer to it by key.
#Nickname ididnteditheconfig

## Define these to limit how much relayed traffic you will allow. Your
## own traffic is still unthrottled. Note that RelayBandwidthRate must
## be at least 20 kilobytes per second.
## Note that units for these config options are bytes (per second), not
## bits (per second), and that prefixes are binary prefixes, i.e. 2^10,
## 2^20, etc.
#RelayBandwidthRate 100 KBytes  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
#RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KBytes # But allow bursts up to 200KB (1600Kb)

## Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
## Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
## not to their sum: setting "40 GB" may allow up to 80 GB total before
## hibernating.
##
## Set a maximum of 40 gigabytes each way per period.
#AccountingMax 40 GBytes
## Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
#AccountingStart day 00:00
## Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
## is per month)
#AccountingStart month 3 15:00

## can explain what Tor is if anybody wonders why your IP address is
## contacting them. See contrib/tor-exit-notice.html in Tor's source
## distribution for a sample.
#DirPortFrontPage /opt/local/etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html

## Uncomment this if you run more than one Tor relay, and add the identity
## key fingerprint of each Tor relay you control, even if they're on
## different networks. You declare it here so Tor clients can avoid
## using more than one of your relays in a single circuit. See
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#MultipleRelays
## However, you should never include a bridge's fingerprint here, as it would
## break its concealability and potentially reveal its IP/TCP address.
#MyFamily $keyid,$keyid,...

## A comma-separated list of exit policies. They're considered first
## to last, and the first match wins.
##
## If you want to allow the same ports on IPv4 and IPv6, write your rules
## using accept/reject *. If you want to allow different ports on IPv4 and
## IPv6, write your IPv6 rules using accept6/reject6 *6, and your IPv4 rules
## using accept/reject *4.
##
## If you want to _replace_ the default exit policy, end this with either a
## reject *:* or an accept *:*. Otherwise, you're _augmenting_ (prepending to)
## the default exit policy. Leave commented to just use the default, which is
## described in the man page or at
## https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html
##
## Look at https://www.torproject.org/faq-abuse.html#TypicalAbuses
## for issues you might encounter if you use the default exit policy.
##
## If certain IPs and ports are blocked externally, e.g. by your firewall,
## you should update your exit policy to reflect this -- otherwise Tor
## users will be told that those destinations are down.
##
## For security, by default Tor rejects connections to private (local)
## networks, including to the configured primary public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses,
## and any public IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on any interface on the relay.
## See the man page entry for ExitPolicyRejectPrivate if you want to allow
## "exit enclaving".
##
#ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:* # allow irc ports on IPv4 and IPv6 but no more
#ExitPolicy accept *:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv4 and IPv6 as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy accept *4:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv4 only as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy accept6 *6:119 # accept nntp ports on IPv6 only as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed

## Bridge relays (or "bridges") are Tor relays that aren't listed in the
## main directory. Since there is no complete public list of them, even an
## ISP that filters connections to all the known Tor relays probably
## won't be able to block all the bridges. Also, websites won't treat you
## differently because they won't know you're running Tor. If you can
## be a real relay, please do; but if not, be a bridge!
#BridgeRelay 1
## By default, Tor will advertise your bridge to users through various
## mechanisms like https://bridges.torproject.org/. If you want to run
## a private bridge, for example because you'll give out your bridge
## address manually to your friends, uncomment this line:
#PublishServerDescriptor 0
MaxCircuitDirtiness 60
```

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like you're specifying the ports on the command line but it's trying to bind to them *twice*, are they already defined in the file `/opt/local/etc/tor/torrc`?

Comment: I don't sepcify it anywhere -- I have edited my question to include the configuration file

Comment: Are you sure? e.g. `[warn] Option 'CookieAuthentication' used more than once...` suggests that again it is reading that option from somewhere else but the command line. Is it possible you've set `tor` as an `alias` in `bash` or something similar? The fact the lines appear twice and it complains about other config options being specified twice while they're not in the config suggests its getting them from somewhere. (p.s. there's no good reason for specifing `maxcircuitdirtiness` like that except if you want to be less anonymous)